# I DO want Flash to autoplay!

Tags: flash, video, swfobject

I've got an issue that I'm not sure is workable, but here goes - 
I'm using swfObject to embed some Flash video on a page, and am passing it a previously built player I was hoping to use. Everything works fine, but I'd like the .swf to autoplay (it's loaded in a jQuery lightbox). I'm beginning to think I can't force it without altering the original .fla file, which I don't have. So, if it's possible, let me know and I will forever be indebted.
Code:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

                var params = {
                    allowFullScreen: "true"
                };

                var flashvars = {
                    video: "...voices_final.mov",
                    maintainAspectRatio: "false"
                };

                var attributes = {};
                swfobject.embedSWF("...videoPlayer.swf", "voices-flash", "720", "405", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
            }
        });
```

Comment: The SWF should "play" once loaded... do you mean you want the video to autoplay?

Comment: Yep - It loads and shows fine, but just takes another click on the play button to play the video. I was hoping there's a way to override this in the params since I don't have the original .fla file.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the programmed features and behaviors of the SWF. For example, FlowPlayer has a special flashvar for instructing the player to autoplay a video.

Your SWF will need to have ability.

Answer (score 0):

You could decompile the SWF and see if there's a public function that starts the video. Then you can create an app that loads the SWF and executes the public function. Or maybe even easier, you could try adjusting the code in the decompiled SWF so it autostarts and try to recompile it.